# Max duration for azure Api Management cache

Tags: azure-api-management

Trying to find somewhere where it explicitely says the maximum number of seconds allowed for the duration in the *cache-looku*p policy for Azure Api Management, but can't see any result

I have seen a sample where it's set to match the *max-age* value from the header the backend service sends, so I assume i is the seconds in a year as a minimum. At the same time I have seen it's stored as an `int?`so maybe is the maximum int value in .net?

Thanks

Comment: "Note that cache duration is set to the max-age value provided in the Cache-Control header received from the backend service or to the deafult value of 5 min if none is found " Reference: https://github.com/Azure/api-management-samples/blob/master/policies/Set%20cache%20duration%20using%20cache%20control%20header.policy.xml

Comment: `@(context.Variables.ContainsKey("maxAge") ? int.Parse((string)context.Variables["maxAge"]) : 3600)` 
Reference: [API Management policy expressions - Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#PolicyExpressionsExamples)

Comment: Wil do @DeepDave-MT,wasn't sure how to raise the question to them so this is really helpful. The other links, yes I had seen them but they don't clarify the maximum. Thanks